# FFMPEG Permission denied on file in NTFS

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, permissions, ntfs

FFMPEG won't read a file on my NFTS partition, even with sudo, giving the error "Permission denied". Something to do with whitelist and crypto? Full log:

```
$ cp a.mp3 b.mp3

$ ls -l ?.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ricardo ricardo 4175244 set 29 13:43 a.mp3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ricardo ricardo 4175244 set 29 13:45 b.mp3

$ ffmpeg -i b.mp3 -c copy c.mp3 -loglevel 56
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error:  GLXBadContext
  Request Major code 156 (GLX)
  Request Minor code 6 ()
  Error Serial #55
  Current Serial #54
ffmpeg version n4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libdrm --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'b.mp3'.
Reading option '-c' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option 'c.mp3' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument '56'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument 56.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url b.mp3.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: b.mp3.
[NULL @ 0x779340] Opening 'b.mp3' for reading
[file @ 0x779cc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
b.mp3: Permission denied
```

Comment: ffmpeg might have come with some outdated shared libraries that duplicate yours. Verify using `ldd` which ones it uses and you might need to rename some libraries in its folder.